# How can I determine the primary key of a table in postgres with C++ and libpqxx?

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

My task is to determine the primary key of a postgres table with libpqxx (dynamically), but I don't know how to bind the value correctly. I get syntax error.

```
std::string sql =
           "SELECT c.column_name, c.data_type "\
            "FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc" 
            "JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu USING (constraint_schema, constraint_name)" 
            "JOIN information_schema.columns AS c ON c.table_schema = tc.constraint_schema "
            "AND tc.table_name = c.table_name AND ccu.column_name = c.column_name "
            "WHERE constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY' and tc.table_name = '$1';";


     C->prepare("determine_primary_key", sql.c_str()); 

     pqxx::prepare::invocation  w_invocation = W->prepared("determine_primary_key");


    std::vector<std::string > vect;

    vect.push_back("postgres_table_name");

    prep_dynamic(vect, w_invocation);

    pqxx::result r = w_invocation.exec();
```

Comment: If I try to run the select in postgresql it didn't give anything back. (Postgres doesnt offer the possibility to bind something to $1.) If I try to run the select without apostrofs (') at  $1 it gives syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for pqxx, the `prepared()` method is deprecated.  So using your code snippet I would make the following changes to use the new `exec_prepared()` statement and pull in your parameter:

```
std::string sql =
       "SELECT c.column_name, c.data_type "\
        "FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc" 
        "JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu USING (constraint_schema, constraint_name)" 
        "JOIN information_schema.columns AS c ON c.table_schema = tc.constraint_schema "
        "AND tc.table_name = c.table_name AND ccu.column_name = c.column_name "
        "WHERE constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY' and tc.table_name = '$1';";


 C->prepare("determine_primary_key", sql.c_str()); 

 pqxx::result r = W->exec_prepared("determine_primary_key", "<your_table_name_here>");
```

But, if you are still using the older version of pqxx and need to keep using `prepared()` you can do the following:

```
std::string sql =
       "SELECT c.column_name, c.data_type "\
        "FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc" 
        "JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu USING (constraint_schema, constraint_name)" 
        "JOIN information_schema.columns AS c ON c.table_schema = tc.constraint_schema "
        "AND tc.table_name = c.table_name AND ccu.column_name = c.column_name "
        "WHERE constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY' and tc.table_name = '$1';";

 C->prepare("determine_primary_key", sql.c_str()); 

 pqxx::result r = W->prepared("determine_primary_key")("<your_table_name_here>").exec();
```

You can check the [libpqxx](https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/6.4/a01259.html#a88d721b6b365e74877a3b4e05eb6f69f) documentation to get more info on `prepared()` and `exec_prepared()`.